# Unable to send mail in opencart

Tags: opencart

I have created a new information page named as request. In this I have added the following code

{
        $mail = new Mail();

```
        $namess = $this->request->post['name'];
        $emailss = $this->request->post['email'];
        $phoness = $this->request->post['phone'];
        $phoness2 = $this->request->post['phone2'];
        $enquiryss = $this->request->post['enquiry'];
        $conve = $this->request->post['contactviae'];
        if($conve == '1')
        {
            $emailsss = "Yes";

        }
        else
        {
            $phonesss = "Yes";
        }
        if(!isset($emailsss)){
            $emailsss = "No";
        }
        if(!isset($phonesss)){
            $phonesss = "No";
        }

        echo $body = "Hello Admin <br/><br/> You have recieved a request for product. The details for your product is as follow : 
        <br/><br/><table border='1'><tr><td>Name</td><td>$namess</td></tr><tr><td>Email</td><td>$emailss</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Phone No</td><td>$phoness</td></tr><tr><td>Secondary Phone</td><td>$phoness2</td></tr><tr><td>Enquiry</td><td>$enquiryss</td></tr><tr><td>Contact Via Email</td><td>$emailsss</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Contact Via Phone</td><td>$phonesss</td></tr></table><br/><br/>Thanks & Regards";

        $mail->protocol = $this->config->get('config_mail_protocol');
        $mail->parameter = $this->config->get('config_mail_parameter');
        $mail->smtp_hostname = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_hostname');
        $mail->smtp_username = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_username');
        $mail->smtp_password = html_entity_decode($this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_password'), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        $mail->smtp_port = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_port');
        $mail->smtp_timeout = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_timeout');

        $mail->setTo($this->config->get('config_email'));
        $mail->setFrom($this->request->post['email']);
        $mail->setSender(html_entity_decode($this->request->post['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
        $mail->setSubject("Request a product");
        $mail->setHtml($body);

        $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('information/request/success'));}
```

But after submitting the button it is redirecting to success page but not getting any mail. Plz help me what I am missing

able to send mail through contact page

Comment: make sure you can call the function after you press button submit

Answer (score 0):

Do you set the email configuration in the admin? It's in System > Settings > (Edit the store) > Mail

Comment: this should be a comment (not an answer)

Comment: I have written that I am able to send mail throough contact page means the setting is correct

Comment: Do you missing the line $mail->send();?

Comment: Thanks I forget to use send